# What does the scope resolution operator mean when used after a typename?

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code that's throwing me a bit off:

```
template <typename T, typename K>
struct __UJstruct
{
    ...
    char lchar[K::hLen];
    ...
};
```

What does `K::hLen` do in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, `hLen` is most likely a static data member of the class `K`. Static data members belong to the type as a whole rather than an individual object, and if you don't have a `K` object you can still refer to them like this.

Another possibility is that `hLen` could be part of an `enum` declared inside `K`, like this:

```
class K
{
public:
    enum Dimensions
    {
        hLen,
        hHgt,
        hDpth
    };

    ...
};
```

In other contexts, you could also use the `::` operator to refer to a type declared inside `K`, like this:

```
class K
{
public:
    class J
    {
        ...
    };

    ...
};

...

K::J j;
```